# Give equation of g(t) = |t-2| / t and sketch a graph of slope of the tangent line as t varies from 0 to 4.

Tags: calculus, limits

I need help answering the following question(s):
Plot $g(t) = \frac{\vert t-2 \vert}{t}$ and sketch a graph of slope of the tangent line as t varies from 0 to 4. Give equation.

Still not exactly sure how to get the tangent line and equation.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two cases:

1. $t\ge2$, so $\displaystyle g(t)=\frac{t-2}{t}$.
2. $t<2$, so $\displaystyle g(t)=-\frac{t-2}{t}=\frac{2-t}{t}$.

Case 1: $\displaystyle g(t)=\frac{t-2}{t}$.

- The derivative is $\displaystyle
     g'(t)=\frac{t-(t-2)}{t^2}=\frac{2}{t^2}$, hence the function is
  monotonically increasing.
- The function has no intersection with the y axis, as $t=0$ is not in
  the domain.
- The intersection with the x axis is the point $(2,0)$.
- The horizontal asymptote is $y=1$.

Now you can plot the function in the domain $(2,\infty)$.

Case 2: $\displaystyle g(t)=\frac{2-t}{t}$.

- The domain of the function is $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,2)$.
- The derivative is $\displaystyle g'(t)=\frac{-t-(2-t)}{t^2}=-\frac{2}{t^2}$, hence the function is monotonically decreasing in its domain.
- The function has no intersection with the y axis as $t=0$ is not in the domain.
- The function has no intersection with the x axis.
- The horizontal asymptote is $y=-1$

Now you can plot the function in the domain $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,2)$.

The slope on the tangent line is the value of the derivative, so depending on the domain of t we can write that the slope is $\displaystyle\frac{2}{t^2}$ or $\displaystyle-\frac{2}{t^2}$.

Assume that the tangent line is passing through an arbitrary point which is on the graph. How can you find its equation? BTW, what is $g'(2)$?

Comment: This answer is very thorough, thank you. I'll work on this and figure out the equation and g'(2).